# Proving an inequality involving product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n,d,\ell$ be positive integers such that $d\ge 2$ and $n\ge d\ell$.

Suppose that $k$ is an integer such that $1+\ell\le k\le n-\ell$, i must prove that
$$
\sum_{\substack{i+j=d-1\\ i,j\ge0}}\binom{k-\ell-(i-1)(\ell-1)}{i}\binom{n+1-k-\ell-(j-1)(\ell-1)}{j}\ge \binom{n+1-2\ell-(d-2)(\ell-1)}{d-1}
$$
I thought to use induction maybe? But I don't know how to manipulate a product of two binomial coefficients.

**Here is what I've tried** First, we can rewrite the sum in a more convenient as way:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\binom{k-\ell-(i-1)(\ell-1)}{i}\binom{n+1-k-\ell-(d-2-i)(\ell-1)}{d-1-i}\ge \binom{n+1-2\ell-(d-2)(\ell-1)}{d-1}.
$$

Any help is appreciated.